# Basis of a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\text{Let W = }\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
    x  \\
    y  \\
    x \\
    -y   
  \end{bmatrix} \bigg| , x, y \in \mathbb R \right\} \text{ W is a subspace of } \mathbb R^4
$$

$$\text{Is B = }\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    1 \\
    -1   
  \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    1 \\
    0   
  \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    -1  \\
    0 \\
    1   
  \end{bmatrix}  \right\} \text{ a basis for W?}
$$

My textbook covers nothing on a basis of a subspace and my notes only has this example. I'd post the solution from my notes but I don't like how they did it because if I were to change the numbers slightly i'd be really confused. I'm really looking for a easy way to do this question because it really confuses me. Could I maybe put the matrix B in the form of: $rv_1 + rv_2 + rv_3 = 0$, then see if they are linearly independent or not? If they are linearly independent i can say that this is a basis for the subspace?

Comment: Well, it's a two-dimensional subspace (which you can see since you only need two variables $x$ and $y$), so you'd expect a basis to consist of only two vectors. Surely, if you add the first and the third, you get the second one, so they are linearly dependent. However, picking any two of the three is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

To prove that $W$ is a vector space take two vectors
$$
\mathbf v=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\v_2\\v_1\\-v_2
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\mathbf u=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\u_1\\-u_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and shows that 
$$
a \mathbf v+ b \mathbf u=a\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\v_2\\v_1\\-v_2
\end{bmatrix}
+ b
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\u_1\\-u_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has the form $[x,y,x,-y]^T$

For the second question note that the second vector is the sum of the oter two.